# Problem when using group_concat_max_len after jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code on my page to extend string length from 1024 and it works fine.

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 2000');
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("....
```

The issue is when I use the identical code on a page which is used for a jquery ajax post, the max_len stops working - it defaults back to the original server setting. Everything else that comes back from the ajax post works fine except group_concat_max_len.

My ajax post code -

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'xxxxxx/getData3.php',
                data:'id='+pager,               
                beforeSend:function(){
                    jQuery('#infp').show();         
                },
                success:function(html){
    jQuery('#resulting').replaceWith(html);
    }
            });
```

Anyone have any ideas on why group_concat_max_len stops working after ajax?

Comment: Please share the code in question, as in: the PHP code. I don't think that this is related to AJAX in any way

Comment: Sorry i added more code

Comment: Where's the PHP code you are calling? Again: I don't think that AJAX is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`SET SESSION` will only update the value for the current connection, in this case the query run by your ajax script, and will not persist to your other connections.

You should set this globally using `SET GLOBAL` or in your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: brilliant tks so much will give it a try

Comment: I do have the same session code on the page called in the ajax post, do you mean change it here or on the page I post from, or on both? tks

Comment: no luck, it goes back to 1024 when i use SET GROUP group_concat_max_len... I am on shared hosting maybe i will have to use .cnf file tks